# How do multiple && and || work with if statements

Tags: bash

I know that `&&` is AND, and that `||` is OR. But how do they work with each other when you have multiple of them? See (the statements are replaced with numbers):

```
if 1 && 2 || 3 && 4
->
 1) (1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)
 2) 1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4


if 1 && 2 || 3 && 4 || 5 && 6
->
 1) (1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4) OR (5 AND 6)
 2) 1 AND (2 OR 3) AND (4 OR (5 AND 6))
 etc. etc.
```

So: How do multiple `&&`'s and `||`'s work? Is there an order (e.g. `&&` is always above `||`), or just "from left to right", or something else? What if the if-statement works like possibility 1, while you want it to work like possibility 2? What can you do then?

Comment: Do you mean precedence on boolean operators on Bash? [This might help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88851/209677)

Answer (score 2):

This is called "operator precedence" in computer science lingo, and if you search `man bash` for `precedence` you will find the answer to your question:

```
          Expressions may be combined using the following operators,
          listed in decreasing order of precedence:

          ( expression )
                 Returns the value of expression.  This may be used to
                 override the normal precedence of operators.
          ! expression
                 True if expression is false.
          expression1 && expression2
                 True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
          expression1 || expression2
                 True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.

          The && and || operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value
          of expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of
          the entire conditional expression.
```

Note the last bit... if you write "if true || something" then "something" will never get done.

Answer (score 0):

@B.Tanner's answer has the right explanation about *operator precedence*. They work simply from left to right.

For your examples, it means:

```
if 1 && 2 || 3 && 4
--> (((1 && 2) || 3) && 4)

if 1 && 2 || 3 && 4 || 5 && 6
--> (((((1 && 2) || 3) && 4) || 5) && 6)
```

If any evaluation fails, `bash` does not consider the rest.

Comment: Second if statement; 2nd possibility: It can be done turning the statement around, but I'm having problems. `5 && 6 || 4 && ...` is what I have now, but the `(2 OR 3)` is a problem. I'm getting `... (4 AND 3) OR 2` instead of `... 4 AND (3 OR 2)` which is logical, but how can I get it to work? Perfectly visible in your answer is that you start with opening `(((((` and then close them one by one. The problem now is that I need to "open" a `(` in the middle of the statement.